# FreeBSD and GNU/Linux system calls compatibility library

Tags: linux, freebsd, system-calls

Is there any C library for FreeBSD that emulates GNU \ Linux system calls, something like syscall wrapper? I am trying to port my library to FreeBSD and it's very insidiously when my program has been compiled without errors but system calls make a little bit other things than I expected.

Comment: You might study what other foreign software does in the FreeBSD ports system to work-make-do.

Comment: The more usual route is to fix one's program to be properly portable, both in the library functions that it calls and in what it expects those functions to do.

Comment: I think it is not enough to emulate the bsd syscalls, also a lot of other things is different there, for example: the procfs and the memory model. Although they use elf binary format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other way around there is [libbsd project](https://libbsd.freedesktop.org/wiki/).

As for Linux compatibility on FreeBSD, it has Linux ABI support layer called Linuxulator. You might be able to brand your app as Linux one, so it would be ran under Linuxulator.